# Netbeans GUI programming

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I am currently in Gr 12 and recently we received a assessment task. The task asks us to create GUI screens and then code everything behind it. Problem is that our teacher never explained to us how to code GUI screens and since exams are approaching, she won't really help us. I created the GUI screens in Netbeans using  JFrame forms. From there on out, I am lost. I am using a text file to read from and I know how to code an array, display and basic class. I need help though because I don't even know where to start. If someone can help me, it would be greatly appreciated. Even if we need to talk about it more somewhere. Thank you

Comment: open netbeans and do: newProject->Samples->java->Gui Form examples

Comment: For eg: If you have a button on the GUI, just double click the button and it will take you to the code for the click event. From there on, you should be able to find your way. This question really isn't supposed to be on SO. Something more specific is expected.

Answer (score 4):

Create a new project in NetBeans
and then create JForm by
[image]

then select design from toolbar
[image]
now drag and drop elements from palette

click on button properties then choose ActionPerformed
[image]
this code will generates in source code write code there
[image]

```
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Would be awesome if I could have skyped with someone sometime